# WPF - Using CollectionViewSource is Causing Erroneous Setter Call

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox, collectionviewsource

WPF, MVVM

I'm finding that if I use a CollectionViewSource with my ComboBox, when I close the window, an extra call to the SelectedValue Setter is executing, if SelectedValue is bound to a string property.  If I set the ItemsSource binding directly to the VM, this call does not happen.  The extra call is causing values to change in the VM, resulting in incorrect data.  I have other ComboBoxes setup the same way, but they bind to integer values.

CollectionViewSource definition:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AllClientsSource" Source="{Binding AllClients}" >
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="ClientName" />
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

ComboBox with CollectionViewSource:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllClientsSource}}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ClientName" SelectedValuePath="ClientId"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ClientId}"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEditingPlan, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibility}}" />
```

ComboBox direct to VM (Forgoing sorting):

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding AllClients}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ClientName" SelectedValuePath="ClientId" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ClientId}" 
          Visibility="{Binding Path=IsEditingPlan, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibility}}" />
```

Can anyone tell me why there is an extra setter call using the CollectionViewSource?  What's different about the string binding?  Is there a way to properly work around it?

EDIT:  I tried changing it up and using the SelectItem property on the ComboBox.  Same result.  So it seems that if the item is a scalar data type, it works as expected.  If it's an object, you get an extra setter call with a null value.  Again, if I remove the CollectionViewSource from the equation, it works as expected.

EDIT, AGAIN: I added a link to a [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11594240/CVSTestApp.zip) that illustrates the issue.  Targets .Net 4.5.

- Run the project.
- Click to display View One
- Select a Client and the client's name will display on the right.
- Click to display View Two
- Go back to View One - Note that the selected client is no longer selected.
- Click to display View Three
- Select a Region and the region's name is displayed on the right.
- Go back to View Two
- Go back to View Three - Note that the selected region is still selected.

The only difference between the views is that One and Two use a CollectionViewSource.  Three binds directly to the ViewModel.  When you move to a new tab from One or Two, the setter for the selected item is getting called with a null value.  Why?  What's the best work-around?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a simple test project? I was unable to replicate using the example of above.

Comment: I've worked around it, in the mean time, but I will try to put together a simple test project and post it, when I have a chance.

Comment: No problem, I was just wondering if I was missing something =D

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is caused when the CollectionViewSource is removed from the visual tree...  I moved the CollectionViewSource to the ViewModel and exposed it as a property and the issue is effectively worked-around.